# Get the location of installed application icons on launcher screen

Tags: android

I am trying to find a way to get the location of the installed application icons on the device home screen programatically.

I couldn't find anything in Google’s documentation that is related to that.

Does anyone know how can I achieve that?

Comment: There is no default *home screen*. As such there is no position (at least not on every launcher) and no API to query it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible.

There are over 8,000 Android device models. There will be *hundreds* of different home screen implementations across those models, in addition to hundreds more home screens available from the Play Store or elsewhere.

None of them have to have "installed application icons". I can write a home screen that is a pure text interface.

Certain home screen implementations might have their own public API for getting this information. There is nothing forcing home screen developers to have such an API, let alone have a common implementation of that API.